# Copy data from one table to another NOT avoiding duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Like the title say, I have 2 tables **request** and **request_internal**, both have the same columns and I need to copy the second one into the first one BUT also keeping the columns that have the same primary key. A little example to clarify: if **request** and **request_internal** have a row with id 66 I need to copy the content of **request_internal** and the inserted id value must be 67, 68, etc.

I have been trying and reading a while about this but I can not figure out what SQL query could make.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: show some sample data and results that illustrate what you mean in detail

Comment: and edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table request;` and `show create table request_internal;`

Answer (score 0):

You are describing [`replace into`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html):

```
replace into request ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from request_internal;
```

Comment: I need to add, no replace.

Comment: @NahuCF . . . This does exactly what you describe.

Comment: I read it totally opposite to you, that they want a record added to request for every record in request_internal, but all existing records in request kept (so the new ones need new ids)